# How to set the default namespace or how to define the @key values when using google-api and using Atom serialization/parser

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm having trouble with Atom parsing/serializing - clearly something related to the namespace and the default alias - but I can;t figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have two methods - one that I'm trying to do a GET and see if an album is defined and what that tries to do a POST to create the album (if it does not exist).

The GET I managed to get working - although there too I'm pretty sure I am doing something wrong because it is different from the PicasaAndroidSample. Specifically, if I define:

```
public class EDAlbum  {

    @Key("atom:title")
    public String title;

    @Key("atom:summary")
    public String summary;

    @Key("atom:gphoto:access")
    public String access;

    @Key("atom:category")
    public EDCategory category = EDCategory.newKind("album"); 
}
```

Then the following code does indeed get all the albums:

```
PicasaUrl url = PicasaUrl.relativeToRoot("feed/api/user/default");
HttpRequest request = EDApplication.getRequest(url);
HttpResponse res = request.execute();
EDAlbumFeed feed = res.parseAs(EDAlbumFeed.class);
boolean hasEDAlbum = false;
            for (EDAlbum album : feed.items) {
                if (album.title.equals(EDApplication.ED_ALBUM_NAME)) {
                    hasEDAlbum = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

But - if instead I have:

```
public class EDAlbum  {

    @Key("title")
    public String title;

    @Key("summary")
        public String summary;

    @Key("gphoto:access")
    public String access;

    @Key("category")
        public EDCategory category = EDCategory.newKind("album"); 
}
```

Then the feed has an empty collection - i.e. the parser does not know that this is Atom (my guess).

I can live with the android:title in my classes - I don;t get it, but it works.

The problem is that I can't get the POST to wok (to create the album). This code is:

```
EDAlbum a = new EDAlbum();
a.access = "public";
a.title = EDApplication.ED_ALBUM_NAME;
a.summary = c.getString(R.string.ed_album_summary);
AtomContent content = new AtomContent();
content.entry = a;  
content.namespaceDictionary = EDApplication.getNamespaceDictionary();
PicasaUrl url = PicasaUrl.relativeToRoot("feed/api/user/default");
HttpRequest request = EDApplication.postRequest(url, content);
HttpResponse res = request.execute();
```

The transport and namespace are:

private static final HttpTransport transport = new ApacheHttpTransport(); // my libraries don;t include GoogleTransport.

```
private static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final HttpTransport transport) {

        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
         public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
          AtomParser parser = new AtomParser();
          parser.namespaceDictionary = getNamespaceDictionary();
          request.addParser(parser);
         }
      });
 } 

public static XmlNamespaceDictionary getNamespaceDictionary() {
        if (nsDictionary == null) {
            nsDictionary = new XmlNamespaceDictionary();
            nsDictionary.set("", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
            nsDictionary.set("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
            nsDictionary.set("exif", "http://schemas.google.com/photos/exif/2007");
            nsDictionary.set("gd", "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005");
            nsDictionary.set("geo", "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#");
            nsDictionary.set("georss", "http://www.georss.org/georss");
            nsDictionary.set("gml", "http://www.opengis.net/gml");
            nsDictionary.set("gphoto", "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007");
            nsDictionary.set("media", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
            nsDictionary.set("openSearch", "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/");
            nsDictionary.set("xml", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");
        }
        return nsDictionary;
}
```

If I use

```
@Key("title")
public String title;
```

then I get an exception that it does not have a default namespace:

W/System.err( 1957): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unrecognized alias: (default)
W/System.err( 1957):    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
W/System.err( 1957):    at com.google.api.client.xml.XmlNamespaceDictionary.getNamespaceUriForAliasHandlingUnknown(XmlNamespaceDictionary.java:288)
W/System.err( 1957):    at com.google.api.client.xml.XmlNamespaceDictionary.startDoc(XmlNamespaceDictionary.java:224)

and if I use

```
@Key("atom:title")
public String title;
```

then it does serialize but each element has the atom: prefix and the call fails - when I to a tcpdump on it I see something like

```
.`....<? xml vers
ion='1.0 ' encodi
ng='UTF- 8' ?><at
om:entry  xmlns:a
tom="htt p://www.
w3.org/2 005/Atom
"><atom: category
 scheme= "http://
schemas. google.c
om/g/200 5#kind" 
term="ht tp://sch
emas.goo gle.com/
photos/2 007#albu
m" /><at om:gphot
o:access >public<
/atom:gp hoto:acc
....
```

What do I need to do different in order to use

```
@Key("title")
public String title;
```

and have both the GET and the POST manage the namespace?

Comment: did you figure out? I'm having exact same problem. However I see a test case for this. http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/google-http-client/src/test/java/com/google/api/client/xml/XmlNamespaceDictionaryTest.java?spec=svn7c73e666c8e664f4b7916b5d8176bc94e23eb12d&r=91cb0a5b087cd6bce75b67b0eae5c0c2d14b2b1f#185

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are adding either duplicate dictonary keys or keys that are not understood by the serializer.

Use the following instead.

```
static final XmlNamespaceDictionary DICTIONARY = new XmlNamespaceDictionary()
      .set("", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
      .set("activity", "http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/")
      .set("georss", "http://www.georss.org/georss")
      .set("media", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/")
      .set("thr", "http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the explicit set for the "atom" item namespace solved this issue for me.